# How to convert string 2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago] to localdate?

Tags: java, formatter, localdate

```
selectedStart = "2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago]";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(selectedStart, formatter);
```

I get my `selectedStart` string from a tableview row and try converting it to `LocalDate` but I get the error :

> Text '2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago]' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

I ONLY want the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format do NOT want to get minutes, seconds, timezone etc...

Comment: `selectedStart.substring(0,9)`?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer horrible. Please use the Time API to do this kind of transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient. Note that I used the full date *pattern* for the first transformation, which is needed (`parse` would throw a `DateTimeParseException`).

```
final String selectedStart = "2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago]";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX'['VV']'");
final LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(selectedStart, formatter);
```

Comment: hi, your code is correct i get the localDate like i wanted. However i forgot to mention i dont want a string i want the localdate value with just date in yyyy-MM-dd so i can set the value of a datepicker to that localdate

Comment: @AntonioContreras answer updated. You just need the "parsedDate" variable. A LocalDate contains only the date part.

Comment: private DatePicker modifyAppointmentDate; 
    modifyAppointmentDate.setValue(formattedDate);

Answer (score 1):

## `ZonedDateTime.parse( … ).toLocalDate`

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format but extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets. This extended format is exactly that use by default in the `ZonedDateTime` class.

```
ZonedDateTime.parse( "2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago]" )
```

From that, extract `LocalDate` if you need only the date without the time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = 
    ZonedDateTime.parse( "2019-03-29T10:45-05:00[America/Chicago]" )
                 .toLocalDate() ;
```